# How to have NavBar placed directly against carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I have a navbar and a carousel next to each other, there's a 20 pixel vertical gap
between them. How do I eliminate the gap?

Thanks,

Per

Comment: the gap is probably the margin/padding, you can override the default margin/padding by inspecting the class name for that element and overriding the margin/padding property for that class name

Comment: Code? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

As user814628 said there is a gap below the nav because `.navbar` has a margin bottom css property.  This will fix it:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/kaZcN/6/)